# Java Webcrawler to extract emails

Tags: java, email, web-crawler

I want to write a web crawler that starts at one page and goes to each link on that page looking for an email address. This is what I have so far, but it's not doing anything other than going from webpage to webpage.

```
`package com.netinstructions.crawler;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class WebCrawler {

    private static final int MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH = 26;
    private Set<String> pagesVisited = new HashSet<String>();
    private List<String> pagesToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
    private List<String> emails = new LinkedList<>();

private String nextUrl()
{
    String nextUrl;
    do
    {
        nextUrl = this.pagesToVisit.remove(0);
    } while(this.pagesVisited.contains(nextUrl));
    this.pagesVisited.add(nextUrl);
    return nextUrl;
}

public void search(String url, String searchWord)
{
    while(this.pagesVisited.size() < MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH)
    {
        String currentUrl;
        SpiderLeg leg = new SpiderLeg();
        if(this.pagesToVisit.isEmpty())
        {
            currentUrl = url;
            this.pagesVisited.add(url);
        }
        else
        {
            currentUrl = this.nextUrl();
        }
        leg.crawl(currentUrl); // Lots of stuff happening here. Look at the crawl method in
        // SpiderLeg
        leg.searchForWord(currentUrl, emails);
        this.pagesToVisit.addAll(leg.getLinks());
        this.pagesToVisit.addAll(leg.getLinks());
    }
    System.out.println(emails.toString());
    //System.out.println(String.format("**Done** Visited %s web page(s)", this.pagesVisited.size()));
}
}
```

And this is my Spider Leg Class

```
package com.netinstructions.crawler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SpiderLeg
{
// We'll use a fake USER_AGENT so the web server thinks the robot is a normal web browser.
private static final String USER_AGENT =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1";
private List<String> links = new LinkedList<String>();
private Document htmlDocument;


/**
 * This performs all the work. It makes an HTTP request, checks the response, and then gathers
 * up all the links on the page. Perform a searchForWord after the successful crawl
 *
 * @param url
 *            - The URL to visit
 * @return whether or not the crawl was successful
 */
public boolean crawl(String url)
{
    try
    {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
        Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
        this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
        if(connection.response().statusCode() == 200) // 200 is the HTTP OK status code
        // indicating that everything is great.
        {
            System.out.println("\n**Visiting** Received web page at " + url);
        }
        if(!connection.response().contentType().contains("text/html"))
        {
            System.out.println("**Failure** Retrieved something other than HTML");
            return false;
        }
        Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
        //System.out.println("Found (" + linksOnPage.size() + ") links");
        for(Element link : linksOnPage)
        {
            this.links.add(link.absUrl("href"));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        // We were not successful in our HTTP request
        return false;
    }
}


/**
 * Performs a search on the body of on the HTML document that is retrieved. This method should
 * only be called after a successful crawl.
 *
 * @param searchWord
 *            - The word or string to look for
 * @return whether or not the word was found
 */
public void searchForWord(String searchWord, List<String> emails)
{

    if(this.htmlDocument == null)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR! Call crawl() before performing analysis on the document");
        //return false;
    }
    Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("\"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$\", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE");

    Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(searchWord);

    while (matchs.find()) {
        System.out.println(matchs.group());
    }
}


public List<String> getLinks()
{
    return this.links;
}

}
```

My web crawler was taken from another source and I changed a few things. I added a List to hold the emails and return them all in a list to me. I think I am going wrong in my way that I take the email and put it in the list, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> Spider Leg Class
>
> ```
> Pattern.compile("\"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$\", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE");
> ```

Shouldn't this be...?

```
Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Nothing gets added to the emails, so you need to `emails.push()` the emails you find to the list. Secondly, you probably want to be parsing the HTML document, not the URL of the page. Since the method now doesn't return anything, you need to expand the if statement to avoid the null pointer. The `searchForWord` method should be:

```
public void searchForWord(String searchWord, List<String> emails)
{

    if(this.htmlDocument == null)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR! Call crawl() before performing analysis on the document");
    } else
    {
        String input = this.htmlDocument.toString();

        Pattern pattern =
                Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(input);

        while (matchs.find()) {
            emails.push(matchs.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and it still isn't doing exactly what I was hoping. The list is still filled with empty slots. I do have a question about the regex. If someone had on their site "email me at example@gmail.com." would it still find the email (I ask because it ends with a period and I'm not sure if that would effect it)?

Comment: It's probably because the regex tries to match the whole document as an email, while you want to find the emails themselves. Try it without the end-binding characters on either side "^$"